# Is this the correct way/structure of DDD implementation in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, architecture, domain-driven-design

this may not be the place to ask, but since I am very new at this, can you please tell me if this is the correct way of structuring Domain-Driven-Design in ASP.NET Core.

[image]

To be more specific the way I structured it is based on official Microsoft documentation site.

**Depo.API** *representing* **Application Layer** referencing *Depo.Domain* and *Depo.Infrastructure*

**Depo.Infrastructure** referencing **Depo.Domain** only.

**Depo.Domain** being the core of application.

Please let me know or suggest me anything, and I apologize if this doesn't meet the community guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your implementation is almost correct, but to improve the architecture you can add a layer called SERVICE layer to implement Business Logic. Also, move the Validators and Mapper to the Infrastructure layer. The entire API layer contains only controllers and startup settings.
also You can also use the following link:
[learn.microsoft.com reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/net-core-microservice-domain-model)